# PayPal REST API: Make requests on behalf of a merchant

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm in the process of migrating our software, which makes requests on behalf of merchants to PayPal using the PayPal SOAP API, to the PayPal REST API infrastructure.

I'm using the Client ID / Secret of my PayPal developer account to get a Bearer token from the Sandbox, using https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.

Then I'm doing a call to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders, using our the bearer token just got, to make requests on behalf of a merchant. I'm using the [PayPal-Auth-Assertion](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-requests/#paypal-auth-assertion) header with the following (encoded) JWT-Token:

```
Header:
    {
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
Body: {
  "email": "[merchant e-mail]",
  "iss": "[my client id]"
}
```

The "merchant e-mail" is one of the sandbox accounts I opened in https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

In return I get a `(400) Bad Request {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"No permissions to set target_client_id"}`.

It seems like there must be an additional step for the sandbox account to grant permissions to the developer account. For the SOAP API, I could add the user name of a 3rd party in the following screen [image]. Then I could use the same username as header value for `X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID`. However, I cannot seem to link the sandbox account in the same way, because there is no "third party username" for the main account (the one I'm getting the Client ID from).

What exactly has to be configured to allow these types of 3rd party calls for REST API?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the PayPal-Auth-Assertion header with the following (encoded) JWT-Token:

You need to be a PayPal partner to be using that type of functionality. Contact PayPal if you want to be a partner.

If you want to use their generally-accessible APIs, you have two options.

1. Have every merchant create their own REST API App via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , and copy paste their live client ID and secret into your configuration. This is the best solution, and it is the solution you should pursue.
2. Use the `payee` object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/ , which gives you less control (cannot capture authorizations or issue refunds, for example)

Comment: "You need to be a PayPal partner to be using that type of functionality.": 
are you refererring to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/? In their workflow chart (https://developer.paypal.com/img/docs/partners/setup-flow.png), we can assume that we don't need this for development, only when going live. It that not the case?

Comment: To test commerce platform capabilities in sandbox you do not need approval per se, but you do need guidance and setup

Comment: FYI the actual problem seem to have been that my developer account was not marked as "business account". As soon as I upgraded the account, the API worked :-) I only wish the error message would have been better, this would have saved me 2 days of trying to find out what the problem is.